# Turn on timing on PostgreSQL via SQL

Tags: perl, postgresql, timing

I'm building a full-text search engine using PostgreSQL Full Text Search features.
I want implement it defining a Perl class (using the DBI interface).

The question is: I would like to be able to report the timing for each query to the user: how can I achieve this? I know in psql I have the

```
# \timing
Timing is on.
```

command, but I can't find any reference about having it returned programmatically...
Can it be done at all?

Comment: Yes, it can. Try studying [DBI::Profile](http://p3rl.org/DBI::Profile).

Comment: duplicate of [How can I show the query time in perl, DBI?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10802140/46395)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [`transaction_timestamp()`, `statement_timestamp()` and `clock_timestamp()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT)

```
select
    clock_timestamp() - statement_timestamp() elapsed_time,
    avg(a)
from generate_series(1,10000000) s(a)
;
  elapsed_time   |         avg          
-----------------+----------------------
 00:00:03.700765 | 5000000.500000000000
```

Example asked from comments:

```
select
    clock_timestamp() - statement_timestamp() elapsed_time,
    field
from table
```

Comment: Thanks. Sorry for the silly question, but what is 'a'? And, how is this query related with mine?

Comment: @MarcoS I just gave the engine something to spend time on. It calculates the average of the generated numbers from 1 to 10000000. The important for you is the calculated time interval named `elapsed_time`

Comment: I see. Sorry, I'm quite new with SQL... Can you make an example for the query "SELECT field FROM table", please?

Comment: @MarcoS Example added... If I understand your doubt.